# Open multiple directories with vlc in command line

Tags: command-line, vlc

How can I specify multiple directories to be opened in vlc  ?

```
vlc path/to/folder1 path/to/folder2
```

will ignore folder2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did should work. What happens is that `vlc` opens the first folder immediately and starts playing, so when you look at the playlist, you will see the list of files in the first folder. The second folder is not expanded immediately, so you don't see its files, only its name. For example:

```
$ ls dir1 dir2
dir1:
1.wav  2.wav  3.wav

dir2:
4.wav  5.wav  6.wav
```

If I now open these directories with

```
vlc dir1 dir2
```

I get:

[image: vlc playlist showing dir name]

As soon as the playlist finishes the files from `dir1`, it becomes:

[image: vlc playlist with the contents of dir]

As you can see, both directories were added correctly but the contents of the second are only shown when `vlc` attempts to play them.

If you really need to have the files shown immediately, you can tell `vlc` to open the directories' contents instead of the directories themselves:

```
vlc dir1/* dir2/*
```

Or, if you need that to work recursively and open files in subdirectories as well:

```
shopt -s globstar
vlc dir1/** dir2/**
```

Comment: Is there a way to expand everything right away ? The random  seems to only pick files from the expanded directory until it hits the collapsed ones (if there are a lot of files in the first expanded directory, it's very unlikely to open the other ones at all)

Comment: @mwa1 try double clicking the directory name, that should do it.

Comment: Yes it works , but I meant is there a way to specify to expand in the command line ?

Comment: @mwa1 I don't think so no. As a workaround, load all files instead of just the directories: `vlc dir1/* dir2/*`.

Comment: Nice, I just added ' **/* ' to expand subdirectories. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: There is also `vlc --recursive expand` to expand directories now: https://askubuntu.com/a/1123044/52975

Answer (score 4):

You can also make VLC recursively open all folders with:

```
vlc --recursive expand folder1 folder2
```

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, vlc 3.0.4.

Comment: Also works in Windows!